# Ubuntu Networking Interface Name Help

Tags: networking

If I do an ifconfig I can see I have two interfaces, eth0 and eth1. However if I try and look at the network interfaces from the GUI, by clicking on the drop down menu on the top right of the screen, I can see wired connection 1 and wired connection 2. How do I know which one relates to which eth0 or 1? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you click "Connection Information" in Network Manager, you will see it.

And generally speaking, you either configure network using Network Manager or using CLI and configuration files. It is not supposed to use both.

If you change some settings for an interface in /etc/network/interfaces, Network Manager will stop managing that interface.

Comment: Ah this may be the reason for one of my interfaces not working properly in my machine. I changed a file using nano and now I don't see it in the Network Manager. Pilot6 you are very competent on Ubuntu it seems. Can you give me a couple of links to read about this topic please? Bare in mind that I am super good at networking (it's my speciality) so it's only understanding networking within Ubuntu that I am stuck with and not the actual fundamentals of networking itself.

Comment: @johnsmith You can just use internet search and you will find a lot of links to guides.

Comment: Ok I will do more research and come back if I get stuck. Thanks,